# Blackberry webworks project isnt selectable?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm new in BB app developement

I have downloaded and installed blackberry plugin for eclipse "BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.3.0.201102031007-19".

But when I open it and am going to create new project. I do not find any option for "Blackberry webworkds project"

Can anyone suggest why this may be or how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlackBerry plugin for eclipse is no more available through the eclipse [Update Site](http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java). You can download the complete package/bundle that has the Eclipse and the BlackBerry JDE from their website as you did. The option of "Create a new BlackBerry WebWorks project " has also been removed.

Unfortunately you now need to manually setup your project and put together the config files, javascript files and then test it using Ripple emulator. Available [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/)